# How do I split a number in all possible ways?

Tags: java

I have a number, let's say 123, and I want to generate a List of Lists of all the possible ways to split it:

```
[[1,2,3], [12,3], [1, 23], [123]]
```

I have found a piece of code that almost does this: http://www.quora.com/How-do-I-take-a-string-by-the-user-and-split-it-in-all-possible-ways.

I have modified it a little:

```
class breakString 
{   
    public static List<List<Integer>> res = new ArrayList<>();

public static List<List<Integer>> breaker(String input, int start, int end, List ans)
{
    if(start > end)
    {
        System.out.println(ans);

        res.add(ans);
        System.out.println("res:" + res.toString());
    }
    else 
    {
            ans.add(input.charAt(start) + "");
            breaker(input, start+1, end, ans);

            int listSize = ans.size();
            ans.remove(listSize - 1);
            String lastChar = ans.get(listSize - 2).toString();
            ans.remove(listSize - 2);
            ans.add(lastChar + input.charAt(start) + "");
            breaker(input, start+1, end,ans);
    }
    return res;
}

public static void main(String args[])
{
String input = "123";

List ans = new ArrayList();
ans.add(input.charAt(0) + "");

breaker(input,1, input.length() - 1, ans);    
    System.out.println("----------------------------------------------");

    for (List<Integer> intList : res)
    {
        System.out.println(intList);
    }
}
}
```

But althought it prints the correct solution I can't make it return it right.
The output is:

```
[1, 2, 3]
res:[[1, 2, 3]]
[1, 23]
res:[[1, 23], [1, 23]]
[12, 3]
res:[[12, 3], [12, 3], [12, 3]]
[123]
res:[[123], [123], [123], [123]]
----------------------------------------------
[123]
[123]
[123]
[123]
```

Could you please tell me how to fix it to return:

```
[[1,2,3], [12,3], [1, 23], [123]]
```

Comment: why do you need [12, 3] twice?  Did you mean [1, 23] for one of those tokens?

Comment: Sorry, I have just edited it.

Comment: How is `ans.add(input.charAt(start) + "");`  working? can you paste the code that you actually excuted?

Comment: The above code is the one that I used to produce the given output. It can also be found in the provided link.

Comment: @pantelis300 just change the way you add `ans` to `res`, it will work. I added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using back-tracking you could consider this solution. Assume the input is a number with `n` digits. The number can be split at `n - 1` positions. We can describe each way to split the input number as a string of `boolean` - or as an `int` assuming the input number isn't bigger than 10^32. Now the problem is pretty simple: each distinct way of splitting the input-number is represented by an `int`. 0 would represent no splitting (the original input will be returned) and the number with the `n - 1` least significant bits set to HI would represent splitting into all parts. Now for the implementation:

```
public List<List<String>> split(int in) {
    List<List<String>> result = new ArrayList<>();

    String num = String.valueOf(in);

    //the maximum is to split the number at each possible position
    int maxSplit = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < num.length() - 1; i++)
        maxSplit |= (1 << i);

    for (int i = 0; i <= maxSplit; i++) {
        List<Integer> split = new ArrayList<>();

        //translate the representation of the splitting into the respective indices
        for (int b = 0; b < num.length() - 1; b++)
            if ((i & (1 << b)) != 0)
                split.add(b + 1);

        //ensure that the last part of the solution is in the result
        split.add(num.length());

        //split the input in the specified way
        List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
        int lastSplit = 0;
        for (int s : split) {
            strings.add(num.substring(lastSplit, s));

            lastSplit = s;
        }

        result.add(strings);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That is happening because you are using the same `ArrayList(ans)` in all iterations. So even after adding `ans` to your `res` it's changing(when add `ans` to `res` it's added by reference so changes in next levels will also reflect in `res` that is why you were getting only `123` which was added at the end).

So simply change

```
       res.add(ans);
```

to

```
       res.add(new ArrayList<String>(ans));
```

Everything will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I took the approach suggested by the accepted answer and implemented my own version but without using bit-wise operators and it works for strings or numbers, of any length:

```
public class ListSplitter {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String data = "ABCDEFGHIJK";

    int combinations = (int) Math.pow(2, data.length() - 1);
    for(int c = 0; c < combinations; c++) {
      String pattern = "";
      int half = (int)combinations / 2;
      while(half >= 1) {
        pattern += Integer.toString((int)(c/half) % 2);
        half = (int)half / 2; 
      }
      System.out.println(tokenize(pattern, data));
    }
  }

  private static String tokenize(String pattern, String data) {

    int patternIndex = 0;
    int dataIndex = 0;
    String result="";

    for(int index = 0; index < (data.length() * 2) - 1; index++) {
      if(index % 2 == 0) {
        result += data.charAt(dataIndex++);
      }
      else {
        if(pattern.charAt(patternIndex++) == '1') {
          result += ",";
        }
      }
    }
    return result;
  }
}
```